# How can i get info from a product in the search place with Web Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-analysis

I'm trying to analyze data from a webstore using BeautifulSoup. I need to extract information from the filter search because if I extract it directly for each product item, it may change over time. For example, on this page, I want to extract the price, the title, and the sub-classification (category: bedroom / quality: 400 thread count / size: king).

I have two problems:

Firstly, in the search section, the page doesn't provide the sub-classification for each product. I only found the price and the name.
Secondly, I also tried to classify it myself using the URL, but I see that the page doesn't apply the filter. I mean, regardless of whether I filter by "king" size, the page shows the twin product by default. I have to enter the product and then filter it again to display the correct price.

This is my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def scrape_product_info(product_element, ambiente1, competidor, data_homecollection):
    current_price_element = product_element.find('span', class_='price')
    current_price = current_price_element.text.strip() if current_price_element else None

    previous_price_container = product_element.find('span', {'class': 'price-wrapper', 'data-price-type': 'oldPrice'})
    previous_price_element = previous_price_container.find('span', class_='price') if previous_price_container else None
    previous_price = previous_price_element.text.strip() if previous_price_element else None

    product_name_element = product_element.find('a', class_='product-item-link')
    product_name = product_name_element.text.strip() if product_name_element else "Nombre del producto no encontrado"

    data_homecollection.append([product_name, current_price, previous_price, competidor, ambiente1])

def scrape_url(url, data_homecollection):
    partes_url = url.split('/')
    ambiente1 = partes_url[-1].split('-')[-1].split('.')[0]

    competidor = "Homecollection"

    response = requests.get(url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        elementos_producto = soup.find_all('div', class_='product-item-info')

        for elemento_producto in elementos_producto:
            scrape_product_info(elemento_producto, ambiente1, competidor, data_homecollection)
    else:
        print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
        print(response.text)  # Esto puede proporcionar más detalles sobre el error

# Lista de URLs
urls_homecollection = ['https://www.homecollection.com.ar/ninos/toallas.html',"https://www.homecollection.com.ar/ninos/almohadones-complementos.html", 'https://www.homecollection.com.ar/cuarto/almohadas/almohadas.html']  # Reemplaza 'URL_2' con la segunda URL real

# Inicializar una lista para almacenar los datos
data_homecollection = []

# Iterar sobre las URLs y realizar el scraping
for url in urls_homecollection:
    scrape_url(url, data_homecollection)

# Crear un DataFrame
if data_homecollection:
    columnas = ["Producto", "Precio Actual", "Precio Antes del Descuento", "Competidor", "Ambiente1"]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data_homecollection, columns=columnas)
else:
    print("No se encontraron datos de productos.")
df
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is the information you want in the HTML source, or is it added dynamically by JS?